# Calc : cell format converts empty date to '30/12/1899'

Tags: date, opentbs

In my LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet, I have a block with a line for each data array (with block:tbs-row)
one of the values is a date, which is sometimes empty
With [blk1.DT_FIN_ABONNEMENT;noerr;frm=dd/mm/yyyy;ope=tbs:string], I have a text value when not empty, and an empty cell when the value is empty.

With [blk1.DT_FIN_ABONNEMENT;noerr;frm=dd/mm/yyyy;ope=tbs:date], I have a date value when not empty, and '30/12/1899' when the value is empty. 
I would like to have an empty cell when there is no value.

I tried frm='dd/mm/yyyy|||', frm='dd/mm/yyyy||| ', frm='dd/mm/yyyy|||NULL', frm='dd/mm/yyyy|||#N/A'
and the result is the same

and 
[blk1.DT_FIN_ABONNEMENT;noerr;ope=tbs:string;mok:magnet=tbs:p]
[blk1.DT_FIN_ABONNEMENT;noerr;frm=dd/mm/yyyy;ope=tbs:date;magnet=tbs:p]

breaks the template

Can anyone give me a clue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice (and OpenOffice) has no NULL value for dates. AS soon as a cell is typed as `date`, then it tries to convert it to a date. If a date value is empty then it applies the zero date value, which is set for the Workbook at the option window : Tools/Options/LivreOffice Calc/Calculation.
As you should see, the default `zero date value` is usually set to `1899-12-30`.

Unfortunately, OpenTBS cannot deals yet with this LibreOffice behavior. (OpenTBS  current version is 1.10.0).

A cannot see any simple way to make a workaround.

- Since you use `ope=tbs:date`, then the cell is typed as date, and thus LibreOffice assumes it is `zero date value` when the inner value is empty. By the way, when you use `ope=tbs:date`, then your parameter `frm` is overwritten by OpenTBS.
- Since you don't use `ope=tbs:something`, then the cell is typed as string and you cannot use the cell as a date...

Comment: Thanks, at least you confirm I haven't overlooked something obvious !